# Old sample of sodium tetraphenylborate—why it is red?

Tags: solubility, purification

I have a really old sample of sodium tetraphenylborate. It should be white, but it is red. Does anyone know what was formed and how it influences precipitation of cations in water?

Comment: Hm. How was the sample stored? It might give us an idea of what was reacting with it.

Comment: Yes, more details would be useful.

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics because it was stored about ~30 years in closed bootle, water, oxygen and carbon dioxide could somehow get in. Tetraphenylborate ion does not looks stable in acidic medium, so oxidation of boron atom may begin. These are only my thoughts about what is going on here.

Comment: Haven't found information about tetraphenylborate ion and triphenylborane oxidation products  named boroxines. These could be precipitated out of  tetraphenylborate ion containing solution with aluminium ion containing solution (aluminium(III) chloride) most likely due to its attraction to oxygen. Feel free to research ;)

Comment: Was the bottle glass, plastic, or metal?

Comment: Glass bottle with plastic covering which was additionally covered with isolating tape (or adhesive tape, i do not know exact English equivalent).

Comment: I work for a company that's produced STPB for 27+ years and I've seen the material decompose\turn colors in glass and plastic. Material shouldn't be stored in metal due to the corrosive nature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Decomposition of Sodium Tetraphenylborate](http://www.osti.gov/scitech/servlets/purl/4971), which relates to the [Savanna River site](http://www.srs.gov/general/about/history1.htm) for nuclear weapons material production,

> Stable aqueous NaTPB solutions are a transparent,
>   flesh-toned color. During the initial stages of decomposition (or
>   instability),the solution turns a golden color. As the quantity
>   of TPB- that has decomposed increases, the solution turns dark
>   red, then brown, and eventually black.

In the presence of oxygen "phenol and phenylboronic acid
are produced as well as benzene, biphenyl, and other benzene ring
derivatives".